# Python file with buffer interface

Tags: python, struct

I am reading a binary file containing a couple of dissimilar C-like structs, mostly like this:

```
f = open('binary_file.bin', 'rb')
header = struct.unpack("2h3i", f.read(struct.calcsize("2h3i"))
```

I don't like the repetition of the fmt-string `"2h3i"` and just stumbled over `struct.unpack_from()`. Unfortunately a file object seems not to have a buffer interface (I use Python 2.7).

Since the files are typically several GB in size, `data = f.read()` and use `data` instead of `f`, is not an option.

I found that using [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html)  might be the way to go, but unfortunately it seems, that the 'read pointer' is not advanced when unpacking_from a mmap.

```
f = open('binary_file.bin', 'rb')
mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
print mm.tell()  # --> 0
header = struct.unpack_from("2h3i", mm)  # yeah!
print mm.tell()  # --> 0 why?
```

But I could go ahead and implement my own `unpack_from` like this.

```
def unpack_from(fmt, buffer):
    result = struct.unpack_from(fmt, buffer)
    buffer.seek(struct.calcsize(fmt), 1)
    return result
```

Is this considered a reasonable solution?